# Xcode game Won't Run "Unknown class SKView in Interface Builder file."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm getting this when I try to Run my game with the simulator

"Unknown class SKView in Interface Builder file."

Here is some of the code

```
    // Strings

scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: 0"];
liveString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LIVES: 0"];
```

It says thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 on the side in greed next to the "liveString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LIVES: 0"];"

Something about this as well with the thread 1 breakpoint 1.1

```
0x108f6a361:  movq   0xc70970(%rip), %rsi      ; "_embeddedDelegate"
```

I'm new to this coding in Xcode and don't understand what to do! Help please :)

Thanks, Cody.

Comment: Have you added the SpriteKit framework to your project?

Comment: @luk2302 I have added it and have just gotten 2 errors when I tried to run it when I added it to the Library.

Comment: I was just asking because you seem to want to use SKView which is part of the SpriteKit Framework. Do different errors appear now?

Comment: @luk2302 well when I added the SpriteKit Framework to the Link Binary with Librares I get this new error when trying to run it "clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Are you intending to use SpriteKit or why do you want to use SKView? I can´t help you with that sadly...